# How can I make Assetic automatically move CSS background images from my Bundle to the Web directory?

Tags: symfony, sass, symfony-2.1, compass-sass, assetic

After a great deal of hassle using [Alexandre Salomé's [nonetheless excellent] "Sass, Compass, and Assetic in 10 minutes"](http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Sass-Compass-Assetic-In-Ten-Minutes) I've finally gotten the Compass Assetic filter to convert my SCSS files into CSS files within the /web directory of my project. I even think I've got the compass image-url() function to reference images where they should be.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to keep images inside my bundle and have Assetic properly copy or rewrite them into the /web directory when needed. They just don't go there. For the time being (...and it seems like this may SOMEHOW be the intended functionality??) I'm just copying them into a /web/images directory. That can't be right. ...Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something assetic can and should do, but something Symfony can do.

First of all, you should place the assets on the correct place in your bundle structure. These should be placed in the `Resources/public` directory. This is the place where stylesheets, scripts, images and all other public things lives. For more information about the bundle structure, please read the documentation: ["How to use Best Practices for Structuring Bundles"](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html)

The FrameworkBundle comes with a usefull command called `assets:install` this will install all assets from all bundles into the `web/bundles/<bundle_name>` directory. This command is run every time you use a `composer update` or `composer install` command. When you update some assets in your bundle, you can run this command to copy everything to the web directory:

```
$ php app/console assets:install
```

Sometimes, you don't want to run this command every time you update someting. For instance, if you begin styling your pages, you will need to run that command every minute. If you server supports using symlinks, you can use the `--symlink` option. This way, you don't need to run that command everytime.

Comment: Wouter - you've done it again! This works perfectly; thank you so much. Unfortunately with this in place it seems like I was WRONG about having correctly set up the Compass settings. I'm having difficulty getting it to properly rewrite background images into the /bundles/<name>/... format. But I think that'll be another question!

Comment: @Offlein that is a common problem. You shouldn't use the `@bundle` notation when you have paths to images. For more information see [this issue on the docs](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/1099) and [this reaction by the creator of assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/53#issuecomment-1548080)

Comment: Ah! Insane! I see your comments in there. Thank you so much. That wasn't even what I was trying to use but I see `@MyBundle` is (or will be) the "way" to do it. I'd been attempting to hardcode the compass http_path variable to be /bundles and then hardcode /[[mybundlename]]/images/whatever.png in the Scss file. But I'd never even get /bundles to prepend the image in the output. Regardless, I think I'll hold off until `@MyBundle` notation is working.